# How to work with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

How to restrict the column drag and drop

```js
function drag(ev){
 id=ev.target.id;
 }
function drop(ev){
 id2=ev.target.id;
 //var str=document.getElementById(dict1[id2]);
var str  = "<%= drop12() %>";
console.log(str);
   if(dict[id2]==id){
 ev.target.append(document.getElementById(id));
 console.log(dict[id]);
 console.log(dict1[id2]);
 console.log("hi");
 console.log(document.getElementById(dict1[id2])); 
   }
  else{
 console.log(id);
 console.log(id2);
 console.log(dict[id2]);
    //ev.target.append(id2);
}
}
```

column drag and drop restrictions using html.

Comment: Where is your HTML code? Make a working code snippet please

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `draggable="false"` if you want to **restrict** any element from drag and drop.

To set it in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute('draggable', false);
```

To set it in HTML:

```
<img draggable="false">
```

Check here for more information : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp